# Manipulating CONNECTED frame with Spring WebSocket

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp

We are using Spring WebSocket. And we have a Channel interceptor and can handle `CONNECT` and `SUBSCRIBE` messages to validate and authenticate. The `CONNECTED` frame is sent from the broker to the client in response to the `CONNECT` frame. Is there any way to manipulate this frame? It includes a session id that my boss wants me to remove because he thinks it is a security risk.

Comment: I would try to remove the session id

Comment: My boss wants me to. And honestly I am not sure if it is even a security issue. I dont create the connected frame. Its not from me so...

Comment: I am not even sure if HE can.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've updated your question with the additional details to help others understand your use-case better.